# JQuery Extract Values From XML With NameSpaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xml-namespaces

I have some XML

```
<item>
<language>en-gb</language>
<attr xmlns="wab" name="date" value="23/02/2013 05:35:32"/>
<attr xmlns="wab" name="group" value="alt"/>
<attr xmlns="wab" name="guid" value="9ab6e5cb28bd457fb88fd3f47288fcd4"/>
</item>
```

I can get the language by using the following JavaScript

```
$(this).find("language").text();
```

How would i go about extracting the date, group and guid?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "JavaScript", I believe you mean jQuery.

Comment: Sorry Richard, yes i do, ill change that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this).find('attr[name="date"]').attr("value")
```

See the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: Perfect Richard! Thank you for your help, ill mark it as the answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Use an attribute selector on attr, see doc where something similar is done on input tags:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something to this effect, if you want to find the value of each of the `<attr/>` nodes:

```
var attrs = $("attr");
$.each(attrs, function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("value"));
});
```